# Окно во весь экран, но не во весь

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

На моей форме не так много элементов=> при развёртывания формы во весь экран она смотрится нелепо. Можно ли сделать, чтобы при разворачивании она разворачивалась только по горизонтали?

Comment: `MaximizeBox = false` и задать максимальные размеры формы, я бы так сделал.

Answer (score 0):

У формы есть свойство [`MaximumSize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize?view=net-5.0). В нем можно установить ограничение для высоты формы, а по ширине проставить какое-нибудь большое число:

```
this.MaximumSize = new Size(10000, this.Size.Height);
```

P.S. Не люблю когда приложения за меня решают как они должны разворачиваться, но это уже дело вкуса :)

Comment: Ну и если окно не разворачивается в полный экран по дизайну, то лучше выкинуть кнопку разворачивания формы.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Автор хочет разворачивать окно, только по горизонтали.

Comment: Тогда не понятно в каком положении оно должно оставаться по вертикали: вверху, посередине, внизу или где было.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Я понял что по вертикали, но да, здесь не совсем понятно. Можете уточнить требования у автора.